# xwiki - can't install any extensions

Tags: http-proxy, xwiki

I installed `xwiki` inside `tomcat9` and with `postgresql 14`.
I configured the company proxy in the last line of `/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.64/bin/catalina.sh`.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dappserver.home=$CATALINA_HOME -Dappserver.base=$CATALINA_HOME -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.example.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 $XWIKI_OPTS"
```

But there are no extensions available in the Initialization Wizard of xwiki.
And there is no way to add them later on.
I can import Packages manually in the admin page but it does not do anything.
I can import this `xwiki-platform-distribution-flavor-xip-13.10.8.xip` but nothing happens.
Unzipping it in `/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.64/webapps/xwiki/WEB-INF/extensions/repository` also does not help...

Also how do I reinitialize xwiki to go back to the installation wizard at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unzipped the `standard flavour` extension in the wrong directory.
It has to be in the `environment.permanent_directory` which is given in the `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/xwiki/WEB-INF/xwiki.properties` and the default is `/var/lib/xwiki/data` when you just comment it out.

So I unzipped it in `/var/lib/xwiki/data/extensions/repository/` and then restarted `tomcat9`.
Then the installation wizard automatically came back without doing any reset.
And then I could install all extensions from inside the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your company proxy needs auth? If so - you can use [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) as a intermediate proxy to access your company procy...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).